# Custom Title Bar Button in ListActivtiy

Tags: android

I want to have an CustomTitle bar with some buttons in it within the ListActivity.
Uptill now I am successful in displaying the title bar with some buttons.
But I cannot handle the event of click on those buttons.
Following is my code:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class ProfileListView extends ListActivity {

    boolean done;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("OnResume ProfileListView");
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_list);
        this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.maintitlebar);


        }
}
}
```

When I add the clickListener for the button it gives me error

```
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})
```

I think its because of I have a different Listener for the `ListActivity` and might be its conflicting with this one. Also can it be defined in the `OnResume` method?

Is there any solution with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have imported the wrong OnClickListener. Change:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

to

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You imported `DialogInterface.OnClickListener;` instead of `view.OnClickListener;` import `android.view.View.OnClickListener;` and you will use the correct listener.